# how to playblast camera in Blender?

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

Hello I need to know how to make a "playblast" in Blender, (I.E.: for review by my director). I'm almost sure it will be named differently in Blender, something more sensible like "preview render" or "quickest basic render" or "screen based capture" or something. 
  In any case I need a way to preview my animation and camera work in it's proper timing before going through to the final render. And I'd also like a way that can render a video with the skeleton visible etc. that can be sent to my director elsewhere